# Flutter stepper inside appbar

Tags: flutter, stepper, uistepper, flutter-appbar

Can I use an horizontal stepper widget inside the appbar? If not, how can I "override" the appbar and customize it to do what I want to do?
(I just need 3 steps)
Thanks!

Comment: any reasons you want to use app bar, else you can go with container

Comment: @PiyushKumar , Do you have an example? I haven't can do that before. Thanks

Comment: i will put a code in answer box try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the attribute **bottom** of the AppBar. The stepper needs to be wrapped by a PreferredSize Widget.

```dart
AppBar(
  bottom: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(110.0),
    child: Stepper(),
  ),
  actions: [],
)
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple don't use appBar.
here's the example code

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [Stepper(), //add here the other widgets you want]);
```